# Using Xcode 5 and iOS 6.1 as base SDK problems

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I added the 6.1 SDK to my Xcode 5 in order to be able to enjoy Xcode 5 features and still develop with base SDK 6.1. The results are strange.

For some reason when I want to test the app on my device, I get two "iOS device" options to choose from. Both looks the same but act different. One will actually use SDK 6.1 and the other one will use SDK 7.0 navigation bar. Any clue why that is?

[image]

Comment: You do understand that you can link to the iOS 7 SDK and still run your code on devices all the way back on 2.x?  You just have to limit yourself to the functions available on the lowest common denominator SDK.

Comment: @CodaFi, Not fully accurate as the UINavigationBar becomes like the iOS 7 style and I would like to keep the UINavigationBar of the iOS 6.

Comment: That has nothing to do with what I just said.  That UIKit is different on different devices is something you have to work around with either UIAppearance or a custom navigation bar.

Comment: Isn't the UIKit depended on the base SDK? Cause when I run base SDK 6.1 it shows the old UINavigationBar, and the opposite.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I was talking about when I mentioned UIAppearance.  My point is that you can still link with a higher-versioned SDK and run code on a lower-versioned devices without having to install extra SDKs.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have multiple SDKs in your application..

It works just like multiple simulators however apple doesn't label each iOS SDK.

You can tell what one is what as they are in numerical order so the 6.1 SDK will be at the top and 7.0 SDK will be at the bottom.

---

It's important to note that after you make changes in various places, the selected option likes to reset itself back to the top one. This can be very frustrating at times.

Also, when you archive builds it is important to make sure you have correctly selected the SDK here as the base SDK in build settings seems to be ignored

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to have native iOS 6.1 views running in iOS 7, you need to add the 6.1 SDK to Xcode (as you did), and go to Build Settings and set the Architecture SDK and the Deployment Target to 6.1.

To test your app select the upper device in the list (the other one is apparently to ignore the previous settings)